# Converting a tf.dataset to a PyTorch Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I'm working on this project where all the data comes preprocessed and ready as a TensorFlow dataset which looks like this:

> <MapDataset shapes: {input_ids: (128,), input_mask: (128,), label_ids: (), segment_ids: (128,)}, types: {input_ids: tf.int64, input_mask: tf.int64, label_ids: tf.int64, segment_ids: tf.int64}>

The script that I have is in PyTorch and takes in a Dataset object which looks like this:

```
Dataset({
    features: [
        'attention_mask', 
        'input_ids', 
        'label', 
        'sentence', 
        'token_type_ids'
    ],
    num_rows: 12
})
```

Is there any way to convert one to the other? I'm quite new to both of these APIs so I'm not too sure how they work. Can I potentially convert one to the other?

Answer (score 1):

I use `tfds.as_numpy(dataset)` as the dataloader for my model training. To convert the data passed to my model, I use `torch.as_tensor(data, device=<device>)` inside my model's forward function.

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import torch.nn as nn

def train_dataloader(batch_size):
    return tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load('mnist').batch(batch_size))

class Model(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.as_tensor(x, device='cuda')
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

[Keras-Core](https://keras.io/keras_core/announcement/) - Keras Core is a full rewrite of the Keras codebase that rebases it on top of a modular backend architecture. It makes it possible to run Keras workflows on top of arbitrary frameworks — starting with TensorFlow, JAX, and PyTorch.

> ... You can train a `Keras Core + TensorFlow` model on a `PyTorch DataLoader` or train a `Keras Core + PyTorch` model on a `tf.data.Dataset`.

---

It's a late answer but it might help future readers. Though it's not a great solution, currently there are some discussions going on that might help, i.e. [link 1](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/17698), [link 2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-core)

To demonstrate, we will first build a `tf. data` loader and convert it to `torch.utils.data` loader.

### Build `tf.data`

```py
BATCH_SIZE = 64
(x_train, y_train), _ = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

def normalize(image, label, denorm=False):
    rescale = keras.layers.Rescaling(scale=1./255.)
    norms = keras.layers.Normalization(
        mean=[0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465], 
        variance=[np.square(0.2023), np.square(0.1994), np.square(0.2010)], 
        invert=denorm,
        axis=-1,
    )
    if not denorm:
        image = rescale(image)
    return norms(image), label

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_ds = train_ds.map(normalize)
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=8*BATCH_SIZE)
train_ds = train_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

x, y = next(iter(train_ds))
x.shape, y.shape
(TensorShape([64, 32, 32, 3]), TensorShape([64, 1]))
```

### Build `torch.utils.data`

```py
# Define a custom PyTorch dataset class
class TFDatasetWrapper(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, tf_dataset):
        self.tf_dataset = tf_dataset

    def __len__(self):
        return len(x_train)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return next(iter(self.tf_dataset.skip(idx).take(1)))

def tf_collate_fn(batch):
    x, y = zip(*batch)
    x = torch.stack(x).permute(0, 3, 1, 2).type(torch.FloatTensor)
    y = torch.stack(y)
    return x, y

def iter_tf_data(train_ds):
    x_list = []
    y_list = []
    for data in train_ds.as_numpy_iterator():
        x, y = data
        x_list += [torch.from_numpy(x)] 
        y_list += [torch.from_numpy(y)]
    x_list_cat = torch.cat(x_list, axis=0)
    y_list_cat = torch.cat(y_list, axis=0)
    return [x_list_cat, y_list_cat]
```

```py
def tf_dataset_to_pytorch_dataloader(
    tf_dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0
):
    """Converts a TensorFlow Dataset to a PyTorch DataLoader."""
    data_list = iter_tf_data(tf_dataset)
    pytorch_dataset = TensorDataset(*data_list)
    pytorch_dataloader = DataLoader(
        pytorch_dataset,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=shuffle,
        num_workers=num_workers,
        collate_fn=tf_collate_fn
    )
    return pytorch_dataloader
```

```py
train_ds_torch = tf_dataset_to_pytorch_dataloader(
    train_ds, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE // 2, shuffle=True
)
x, y = next(iter(train_ds_torch))
x.shape, y.shape
(torch.Size([32, 3, 32, 32]), torch.Size([32, 1]))
```

Lastly, let's visualize some examples from `torch` loader.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchvision.utils import make_grid

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.title("CIFAR10 dataset")
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.imshow(make_grid(x, nrow=8).permute(1, 2, 0))
plt.show()
```

[image: download]